How to deal with tangents to circles in complex geometry?
I was having a problem in which I could not define the Tangent to work further in the question. Here is the question -
Let L be the midpoint of the minor arc AC of the circumcircle of an acute-angled
triangle ABC. A point P is the projection of B to the tangent at L to the circumcircle.
Prove that P, L, and the midpoints of sides AB, BC are concyclic.
How do I deal with the tangent here(using complex geometry)? Can you also tell what to do when a tangent comes in the question?

I removed the tag [tag:complex-geometry]. Quoting its description: "For elementary questions about geometry in the complex plane, use the tags [tag:complex-numbers] and [tag:geometry] instead."

Circles in the complex plane work the same as circles in a normal $x-y$ plane.
If $PA/PB=k$, where $k$ is not equal to $0$ or $1$, then the equation $PA/PB=k$ represents a circle. To explain this better I will provide solutions to three such problems which could hopefully clear you doubts.

Find the locus of $z$ ir $|z|=2|z-1|$.
To solve this question we could write it in the form of $PA/PB=k$.
Here it would be |z|/|z-1|=2. We could plot this circle by plotting the critical points represented by $PA$ and $PB$. Here they would be $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ [We found these points by equating $PA$ and $PB=0$. Now from the equation $\frac{PA}{PB}$ We can understand that this is just the ratio of distance of the internal and external point on the circle let us call it A and B [ Similar to the external and internal section formula. We can calculate the points A and B using section formula. A=$(2x_1+\frac{1x_0}{2}+1)$ and $B=(2x_1-\frac{1x_0}{2}-1)$ from here we get A to be $(\frac{2}{3},0)$ and B to be $(2,0)$. The points A and B are the points of the circles diameter. Using formula to find equation of a circle using two points of the diamter we get the formula of the circle to be $(x-2)(x-\frac{2}{3})+(y-0)(y-0)=0$.

Find the complex number having least positive argument and satisfying $|z-5i|\leq 3$.
We could plot the centre of our circle as provided by thr equation. $|z-5i|\leq3$ represents all the points inside the circle centred at $(0,5)$ and having a radius of $3$.
As we need the complex number having the least positive argument it must be a tangent to the circle in the first quadrant. Marking angles and equating thek we get that the required intersection point of circle and tangent in first quadrant is at $P(4\sin(\theta),4\cos(\theta) )$. Here theta is the angle made by the tangent with respect to the x-axis. Theta comes out to be $37$ degrees (from geometry).

What does $arg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ represent.
Here the critical points by equating PA and PB are $(1.0)$ and $(-1,0)$. But as here argument$(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$ is provided, this represents those part of the circle where the angle made by the chords from our critical angle are equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. This can also be solved by geometry as shown in the Figure. I haven't solved your example question to give you a challenge of your own.
Hope this clears all your doubts.



Thanks. This really helped me.

Your welcome, lucky to be helpful to someone else

In the complex plane, the tangent to a curve, say $z(t)$, is given by its gradient, i.e. $\dot z(t)$. The figure below shows the tangent vectors about a circle. Similarly, the normal to a curve is given by $\pm i\dot z(t)$, that is, a $90^{\circ}$ rotation, as shown in the second figure. And while we're at it, the curve length is given by $\int |\dot z(t)|dt$.



Thank you for your insight

Your figures reminds me "Mamikon's methods" : see for example here

@JeanMarie Very interesting. But this was just a simple few lines of Matlab code and using a Matlab built-in quiver function for the plots. Since you brought this up, I repeated the exercise with a random closed curve with the same excellent results.
